# jQuery Test if DOM Element Supports "load" Event

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to check if a jQuery object supports **firing** an event handler for a specific event? I have a function that takes a DOM element and I want to listen for "load" to fade in the element using the following:

```
element.css({ opacity: 0.0 });
element.bind('load', function() { $(this).animate({ opacity: 1.0 }); });
```

Unfortunately, this fails if the passed in element is not an image (as it will always be transparent). Thanks!

Comment: I hate to ask the obvious, but can't you then simply just test to see if the object passed in is an image, and if it is, bind your load event?  It sounds like your function as a whole may only work if it's an image.

Comment: @Adam what's the best way to do this test?

Comment: Please see my post below.  I hope it helps!

Comment: `if ( element.is('img') ) { element.load(function() { ... }); }`

Comment: I suggest rewording your question to ask if it supports binding not firing the event. I was sent here looking for the firing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery can bind the `'load'` event to **any** DOM element (`<==` This never fails). However, that event does *not* fire at any DOM element (It fires at `window`, `document`, scripts, stylesheets, images, iframes, etc.).

If the `'load'` event does not fire at a given element (for instance, a DIV), then there is no point in binding a load handler to that element.

Answer (score 0):

Since my comment seemed to be an acceptable route, here's a more complete answer:

Since it would seem that your function will only work if the passed element is an image, simply test to see if the element passed in is an image:

```
function conditional(element) {
    if(element.tagName == "IMG") {
        element.css({ opacity: 0.0 }).bind('load', function() { $(this).animate({opacity: 1.0 }); });
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cHsMx/2/